# select statement to limit results from combinations in temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I am a total noob here, and I am sure the answer is "well duh", but I'm stumped anyway.

I am selecting from a table and using combinations of two fields from a temp table to limit which records I bring back by joining my table against the aforementioned temp table.

Below is my query:

```
<b>select distinct company3, dept</b>
into #compdept
from fss..budget
where fyr4 = @fyrin and fmo = @fprdin
--select * from #compdept

select
          b.t_year      as fyr4,
          b.t_leac      as acct,
          b.t_cono      as company3,
          b.t_dim1      as dept,
          b.t_fdam - t_fcam       as curactamt,
          b.t_fdam * 0            as curcmpamt,
          b.t_fdam * 0            as ytdactamt,
          b.t_fdam * 0            as ytdcmpamt
    from baan5cdb..ttfgld205110 b
<b>    left join #compdept a on a.company3 = b.t_cono 
    and a.dept = b.t_dim1</b> COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
    where b.t_year  = @fyrin 
      and b.t_prno  = @fprdin
```

The sections in bold above I would think would limit my result set to only company and department combinations that exist in the temp table.

However, I get a company 110, dept 029 in my query result and that combination of company3 and dept do not exist in the temp table #compdept.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: use an inner join, not a left outer join.  An outer join will allow all rows from table `a`, but an inner join will only allow rows that are matched

Comment: Why did you use left join instead of inner join? Time to learn what those do.

Comment: Try a from your temp table and left join baan5cdb..ttfgld205110

Answer (score 0):

Based on your query baan5cdb..ttfgld205110 returns all records and the matched records from the #compdept.

In order to filter only the matched records from #compdept, one option is the [Exists Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql). Example

```
    SELECT  b.t_year AS fyr4 ,
            b.t_leac AS acct ,
            b.t_cono AS company3 ,
            b.t_dim1 AS dept ,
            b.t_fdam - t_fcam AS curactamt ,
            b.t_fdam * 0 AS curcmpamt ,
            b.t_fdam * 0 AS ytdactamt ,
            b.t_fdam * 0 AS ytdcmpamt
    FROM    baan5cdb..ttfgld205110 b
    WHERE   b.t_year = @fyrin
            AND b.t_prno = @fprdin
            AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                             FROM   #compdept a
                             WHERE  a.company3 = b.t_cono
                                    AND a.dept = b.t_dim COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an inner join to the temp table in the second query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      company3
    , dept INTO #compdept
FROM fss..budget
WHERE fyr4 = @fyrin
AND fmo = @fprdin
--select * from #compdept

SELECT
      b.t_year          AS fyr4
    , b.t_leac          AS acct
    , b.t_cono          AS company3
    , b.t_dim1          AS dept
    , b.t_fdam - t_fcam AS curactamt
    , b.t_fdam * 0      AS curcmpamt
    , b.t_fdam * 0      AS ytdactamt
    , b.t_fdam * 0      AS ytdcmpamt
FROM baan5cdb..ttfgld205110 b
INNER JOIN #compdept a ON a.company3 = b.t_cono
      AND a.dept = b.t_dim1 COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
WHERE b.t_year = @fyrin
AND b.t_prno = @fprdin
```

An outer join will allow all rows from table `baan5cdb..ttfgld205110`, but an inner join will only allow rows that are matched to `#compdept`.

**OR** If the intention is to have every row of the temp table listed, even if there are no matching rows, then reverse the table positions in the query:

```
SELECT
      b.t_year          AS fyr4
    , b.t_leac          AS acct
    , b.t_cono          AS company3
    , b.t_dim1          AS dept
    , b.t_fdam - t_fcam AS curactamt
    , b.t_fdam * 0      AS curcmpamt
    , b.t_fdam * 0      AS ytdactamt
    , b.t_fdam * 0      AS ytdcmpamt
FROM #compdept a
LEFT JOIN baan5cdb..ttfgld205110 b ON a.company3 = b.t_cono
      AND a.dept = b.t_dim1
      AND b.t_year = @fyrin
      AND b.t_prno = @fprdin COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select  distinct 
        company3
        , dept
into    #compdept
from    fss..budget
where   fyr4 = @fyrin 
and     fmo = @fprdin

select  b.t_year                as fyr4,
        b.t_leac                as acct,
        b.t_cono                as company3,
        b.t_dim1                as dept,
        (b.t_fdam - t_fcam)     as curactamt,
        b.t_fdam * 0            as curcmpamt,
        b.t_fdam * 0            as ytdactamt,
        b.t_fdam * 0            as ytdcmpamt
from    #compdept a
left 
join    baan5cdb..ttfgld205110 b
        on a.company3 = b.t_cono 
        and a.dept = b.t_dim1  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
where   b.t_year  = @fyrin 
        and b.t_prno  = @fprdin
```